# Parsing commands using map<const string, function<? (?)>> commands;

Tags: c++, function, c++11, dictionary, variadic-functions

**Problem statement:**

Given the interactive input, call the appropriate methods on appropriate objects (Bank, BankRegister, BasicAccount, etc...).

input (each command on a separate line):

```
create_bank <bank_name>\n
create_customer <bank_number> <customer_name>\n
create_account <bank_number> <customer_number>\n
deposit <amount> <account_number>/<bank_number>\n
etc...
```

**Proposed solution:**

```
#include <functional>

bool create_bank(const string& arguments){
    const string& bankName = arguments; //no need to parse here
    bankRegister.registerBank(new Bank(bankName,
                                       &bankRegister)); //can't access bankRegister!
    return true;
}

int main(){
    map<string, function<bool (string)>> commands;
    commands.emplace("create_bank",create_bank);
    ...
    BankRegister bankRegister;

    string command, arguments;
    cin>>command;
    getline(cin, arguments);
    commands[command](arguments);
    ...
}
```

**Why it does not work:**

1. The bankRegister object can't be accessed from the functions. I might pass it by constant reference to the functions, but only some functions need it. I was thinking of making its members (m_banks, m_next_bankNumber) static, but then I would have to make them public, which is probably a bad design decision.
2. Where should the argument parsing happen? Is it OK this way?
3. What should the return value represent?

   a) arguments parsed successfully

   b) arguments parsed successfully and command executed successfully

   I use the exceptions for some of the errors, but some are silent except for cerr.
4. Could I use variadic functions here to parse the arguments?
5. Is there something else you would improve?

Comment: You probably meant `commands[command](arguments)`, without quotes.

Comment: `The bankRegister object can't be accessed from the functions.` So pass it in as an extra parameter. Or, make commands its member functions, and store pointers-to-member in the map.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Of course. Corrected.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I can pass it by extra parameter, but only some functions need it. The others would have to be modified to take parameter they wont use. I can not alter the implementation of BankRegister.

Comment: N.B. there is no point using `std::map<const T, U>`, you probably just want `std::map<T, U>` (the key is always immutable anyway)

Comment: _"I can pass it by extra parameter, but only some functions need it."_ So what? Some functions need it, so they need it. You can't just wish away the fact that they need it. You _could_ make it a global, but that would stink.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Of course. Corrected.

Comment: Which functions can do without it? All commands in the example clearly need some data structure that represents all available banks, accounts and so on. `BankRegister` is that structure, isn't it?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Do I really have to define 10 or more functions with an extra argument they will (and should!) never use or alter?

Comment: That's one option, yes. It would work, which is an improvement over your current code. Another option is to use `std::bind` or a lambda that captures `bankRegister`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I just realized all the commands (including those not mentioned here) DO need BankRegister! So you are right. This part of question is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the signature of the `create_bank` function and use `std::bind` to bind the `BankRegister` argument, creating a function object with the call signature `bool(const string&)`

```
bool create_bank(const string& arguments, BankRegister& bankRegister){
    const string& bankName = arguments; //no need to parse here
    bankRegister.registerBank(new Bank(bankName,
                                       &bankRegister));
    return true;
}

int main(){
    BankRegister bankRegister;
    map<string, function<bool (string)>> commands;
    using std::placeholders::_1;
    commands.emplace("create_bank",std::bind(create_bank, _1, std::ref(bankRegister)));
```

You can do the same thing with a lambda function:

```
    commands.emplace("create_bank", [&bankRegister](const string& args) { return create_bank(args, bankRegister); });
```

The function object returned by `bind` and the closure object created by the lambda expression both have the required call signature, `bool(const string&)`, but they also contain a reference to the `bankRegister` object and can pass it to `create_bank`

Comment: Beautiful. Why do I have to use `std::ref(bankRegister)` instead of `&bankRegister`?

Comment: Because I changed `create_bank` to take a reference to the `BankRegister`, so you need to pass a reference. If you used `&bankRegister` then it would pass a pointer, and so would fail to compile. If you change `create_bank` to take a pointer instead of a reference (as SergeyA did in his answer) then you would use `&bankRegister` as the argument. Basically you need to pass the right thing depending how `create_bank` is declared.

Comment: Accepted for the lambda suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Just use fancy code here:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct BankRegister {
  void create_bank(const std::string& name);
};

void handle_new_bank(BankRegister* reg, const std::string& name) {
  reg->create_bank(name);
}


int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void (const std::string)> > cmds;

    BankRegister reg;

    cmds.emplace("new_bank", std::bind(&handle_new_bank, &reg, std::placeholders::_1));
}
```